# <Div style=> not changing the font

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

I am loading external html files with the following script:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#page1").click(function(){
            $('#result').load('140314F00604.htm');
             //alert("Thanks for visiting!");
           });

           $("#page2").click(function(){
            $('#result').load('140314F029.htm');
             //alert("Thanks for visiting!");
           });

           $("#page3").click(function(){
            $('#result').load('140221F193.htm');
             //alert("Thanks for visiting!");
           });
         });
    </script>
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; border-size: 1px">
        <tr>
          <td><a id="page1" href="#">About</a></td>
          <td><a id="page2" href="#">Community</a></td>
          <td><a id="page3" href="#">Sponsor</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    <div id="result" style="color:red; font-style:italic; font-family:Arial; font-size:12px;"></div>
```

It works perfectly. Load the html file, changes the font color, italic and size, but it does not seem to want to change the font itself to Arial.

The imported HTML looks like this:
[image: HTML Code]

The imported html is generated by software and it can not be edited in the program itself therefore I am trying to load it and change its formatting.

The script below worked perfectly. Unfortunatly the imported html uses spaces to aligh text. Obviously this can not be changed. The working script messes the spacing if you change the font from courier to anything else as can be seen on the images. Is it posible to fix this?

```
function applyPreFont(){
var oldHtml = $('#result pre').html();
$('#result pre').html('<div class="pre-div">' + oldHtml + '</div>');
}

function LoadExternalContent(pagename){
$('#result').load(pagename, function(data) {
    applyPreFont();
    // do other stuff
});
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#page1").click(function(){
    LoadExternalContent('140314F00604.htm');
});

$("#page2").click(function(){
    LoadExternalContent('140314F029.htm');
});

$("#page3").click(function(){
    LoadExternalContent('140221F193.htm');
});
});
```

Original html file

[image]

The output from the script

[image]

Comment: if it is loaded in frame, iframe or object, CSS from the main page or another frameset won't apply.

Comment: where is the code block the do the CSS applies and `result` tag?

Comment: As far as I understand it the javascript pulls the html in, not a frame or iframe.

Comment: Sorry Andre it gets cut off. the result tag looks like this:
<div id="result" style="color:red; font-style:italic; font-family:Arial; font-size:12px;">

</div>

Comment: Where is the font-family defined? Are you sure it is wrapping the content?

Comment: There is nowhere in the jquery documentation for load that says the html is loaded within an iframe.

Comment: try to set on the css: "*, body { font-family: XXX }"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pre` does not accepted css font styling so well. The `fonts` properties will be bypassed,  **even inherited** from parent elements. Even trying to applied it to parent element won't work.

**UPDATE 1** 
**Caution:**
`pre` element uses a font of type `monospace` (All glyphs have the same fixed width), which makes easy for tabular data. Mostly of the fonts (as Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, Times New Roman..) are not monospace, so, each glyph has it own size according to its width.
In the end, the tabular data will not be so "tabular" anymore if you apply non-monospace font. [More on MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family#Values).

You'll have to apply css to a descendant element in `pre`.

As you are using jQuery (and html is dynamic), you can wrap `pre` content into a new `div` with jQuery and apply CSS to its new element:

```
var oldHtml = $('#result pre').html();
$('#result pre').html('<div class="pre-div">' + oldHtml + '</div>');
```

resulting something like this:

```
<pre>
    <div class="pre-div">
        Boland Athletics ...
        ...
    </div>
</pre>
```

I suggest you code like this:

```
function applyPreFont(){
    var oldHtml = $('#result pre').html();
    $('#result pre').html('<div class="pre-div">' + oldHtml + '</div>');
}

function LoadExternalContent(pagename){
    $('#result').load(pagename, function(data) {
        applyPreFont();
        // do other stuff
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#page1").click(function(){
        LoadExternalContent('140314F00604.htm');
    });

    $("#page2").click(function(){
        LoadExternalContent('140314F029.htm');
    });

    $("#page3").click(function(){
        LoadExternalContent('140221F193.htm');
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.pre-div {
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

[**See an example in fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JEag9/1/)

** Tested only in Chrome.

Comment: Where in my script would this go?

Comment: after loading content

Comment: I've updated the answer for your question addition about the tabular space.

Answer (score 0):

The $.load method in jquery has another overload that passes in a callback function. In the documentation, "If a 'complete' callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed.".

I believe you should change your load methods to look like:

```
$('#result').load('140221F193.htm', function(){
   //alert("Thanks for visiting!");
   //set css here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

If you would like everything to align (since PRE uses a Mono Space font) try downloading the Monospace version of Arial ([Download Here](http://www.fontarsiv.com/en/download/font/arial-monospaced) make sure to click the actual download to the right of the font)

the way you would implement it based on your accepted answer and not the removal of the pre tag is through css is:

```
@font-face
{
font-family: arialMono;
src: url(/directory/locationOfFontFile.ttf);
}

.pre-div{
font-family: arialMono;
}
```

Through your Jquery function (after the font is added to a stylesheet) it would be implemented like so:

```
 function applyPreFont(){
    var oldHtml = $('#result pre').html();
    $('#result pre').html("")
    $("<div />",{
    "class": "pre-div",
    html: oldHtml,
    css: {
    "font-family": "arialMono"
    }
    }).appendTo($('#result pre'));
    $('#result pre').html('<div class="pre-div">' + oldHtml + '</div>');

    }
```

---

The problem is with the `<pre>` tags ([Preformatted Text](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp)). Styling that is going to be buggy because of the nature of the tags. Your best bet is to remove the Pre tags via jquery:

```
$('#result').load('140221F193.htm', function(){
   $("#result pre").contents().unwrap()
});
```

That should remove the PRE tags and render the html successfully :)

[JSFidde](http://jsfiddle.net/7dH5G/1/) Here